Can the inequality of integration be kept?
I'm considering two function $f,g\in L^{1}(\Omega)$ which satisfy
\begin{align} \int_{\Omega}f dx\leq\int_{\Omega}g dx\end{align}
Now, if I consider more a function $\phi\in C^{1}(\Omega)$ such that $0\leq\phi\leq1$ in $\Omega$. Will the inequality
\begin{align} \int_{\Omega}\phi f dx\leq \int_{\Omega}\phi gdx \end{align}
still holds true?

No. Counterexamples are fairly easy to invent.

Imagine $f$ the indicator function of $[0,1/4]$ and $g$ the indicator function of $[3/4,1]$. Then put $\phi$ a smooth function that is $1$ on $[0,1/4]$ and $0$ on $[3/4,1]$. You will get $\int f=\inf g$, but $\int\phi f=1/4>0=\int\phi g$. All this for $\Omega=[0,1]$. In some trivial cases of $\Omega$, like empty, or a singleton, your proposition will be true.

If $a \le b$, is $ca \le cb $???
